# Unable to Parse Json (Android login/register)

Tags: java, php, android, json

i need some help concerning a project in Android , its main goal is to connect with a database (register/login) .

The login works just fine but the register shows an error which is i think is an exception , the error is:

```
Unable  to Parse Json
```

the information passed to the database successfully but there is no feedback (response).

I use '**ion**' and **PHP** to *connect/insert/check* the database.
i am using WAMP on Windows.

The code is below :

```
package tn.contacthelpsoft.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText fname,lname,cin,email,pass;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        fname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        lname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        cin= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("erreur","ee");
                Ion.with(Main2Activity.this)
                        .load("POST","http://10.0.3.2/site/register.php")
                        .setBodyParameter("nom",fname.getText().toString())
                          .setBodyParameter("prenom",lname.getText().toString())
                        .setBodyParameter("cin",cin.getText().toString())
                        .setBodyParameter("email",email.getText().toString())
                        .setBodyParameter("pass",pass.getText().toString())
                        .asJsonObject()
                        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                                Log.e("erreur","before");

                                if(e==null){
                                    Log.e("erreur","after");
                                    if(result!=null) {
                                        String res = result.get("success").toString().substring(1, result.get("success").toString().length() - 1);
                                        Log.e("erreur","after++");
                                        if (res.equals("inscrit")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, " inscrit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(in);


                                        } else

                                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "connection ?????"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please share logcat response

Comment: Can't find _Unable to Parse Json_ message in your code. Is it passed from the server? What is the `JSON` you are trying to parse?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . yes it is passe from the server , im using wamp , i am going to post the php script.

Comment: `<?php
    $n=$_POST["nom"];
    $pre=$_POST["prenom"];
    $cin=$_POST["cin"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $pass=$_POST["pass"];
    $var2=null;
    include_once("connect.php");
    $idcon=connecting("helpsoft","set");
    
 
     if($idcon)
        {
     echo "connexion établie......<br><br>";
     $requete="INSERT INTO user values(null,\"$n\",\"$pre\",\"$cin\",\"$email\",\"$pass\")";
     
     
     if($idcon->exec($requete))
     {
      
            $var2['success']='inscrit';
  }
 else
 {
$var2['success']='echec';
   }
   }
 echo json_encode($var2);
 ?>`